# Good home brewing blogs

Tags: first-time-brewer

Any suggestions for good blogs aimed at home brewers?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question for SE, it's open ended and can't have a specific answer.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a dump of all my "Beer & Homebrewing" subscriptions from Google Reader.  If yours is on here and you don't want to be, go ahead and edit it out.  If you're is on here and you want to point out that it's yours, go ahead and denote it as such.  Most of these are about homebrewing, but a few are about beer in general.  If you want to edit those out, feel free.  If you want to add more links, I suggest using this answer as a wiki list of all known blogs.

- [A Good Beer Blog](http://beerblog.genx40.com)
- [Atomic Donkey Brewing](http://atomicdonkeybrewing.blogspot.com/)
- [Bearded Brewing Blog](http://www.beardedbrewing.org)
- [Beer & Whiskey Brothers Blog](http://beerandwhiskeybros.com)
- [Beer Sensory Science](http://beersensoryscience.wordpress.com)
- [BEER THIS!](http://beerthis.blogspot.com)
- [BeerSmith Home Brewing Beer Blog](http://www.beersmith.com/blog)
- [BillyBrew](http://billybrew.com)
- [BYO - Blog entries](http://www.byo.com/blogs)
- [Brew Dudes](http://www.brew-dudes.com)
- [Brewer's Friend](http://www.brewersfriend.com)
- [BrewGeeks](http://www.brewgeeks.com/)
- [Brew Science](http://sciencebrewer.com/)
- [Broken Glass Brewery](http://brokenglassbrewing.blogspot.com)
- [Brush Valley Brewer](http://brushvalleybrewer.wordpress.com)
- [Fairwater Brewery](http://www.fairwater-brewery.co.uk/)
- [Fluke Brewing](http://fluke-brewing.blogspot.com/)
- [Growing Hops Yourself](http://www.growinghopsyourself.com)
- [Homebrew Finds](http://www.homebrewfinds.com)
- [Homebrew Junkie](http://www.homebrewjunkie.com)
- [Homebrewers Association](http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/pages/community/blog)
- [Home Brew Blog](http://homebrewblog.co.uk/)
- [Home Brew Manual](http://homebrewmanual.com)
- [Hopwise Brewery](http://ianwhitney.com/hopwise/)
- [Jay's Brewing Blog](http://jaysbrewingblog.com/)
- [KISS Brew](http://kissbrew.com)
- [Mash.Sparge.Boil](http://www.mashspargeboil.com)
- [Midnight Hour Homebrew-blog](http://midnighthourbrewery.blogspot.com/)
- [Northern Brewer](http://northernbrewer.blogspot.com/)
- [Ryan_PA](http://ryanpa.blogspot.com)
- [Shegogue Brew](http://shegoguebrew.blogspot.com/)
- [Starting a Brewery](http://startingabrewery.wordpress.com)
- [Ted's Homebrew Journal](http://www.tedbrews.com)
- [The Happy Imbibe](http://thehappyimbibe.disqus.com)
- [The Mad Fermentationist](http://www.themadfermentationist.com)
- [The Not So Professional Beer Blog](http://www.notsoprobeer.com)
- [The Perfect Pint](http://perfectpint.blogspot.com)
- [The Screwy Brewer](http://www.thescrewybrewer.com)
- [Trappist Punks](http://trappistpunks.com/index.php)
- [TRASH: Three Rivers Alliance of Serious Homebrewers](http://trashhomebrewers.org/frontpage)
- [Wade's Homebrew](http://wadeshomebrew.blogspot.com)
- [Watch Zach Brew](http://brew.seifts.us)
- [When Yeast Attack](http://www.whenyeastattack.com/) ([JackSmith](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/430/jacksmith)'s blog)
- [Yeastbound & Down](http://www.yeastbound.com)
- [Zythophile](http://zythophile.wordpress.com)

This list includes all of the blogs linked to in all the other answers as of 13:22 EST on Feb. 01, 2011.

Comment: Great list. I miss google reader :(

Answer (score 11):

I enjoy reading [The Mad Fermentationist](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/).

Comment: I've been loving this one...

Answer (score 3):

I run a blog that's aimed at finding good homebrew and beer related deals and unique brewing equipment.

[Homebrew Finds.](http://homebrewfinds.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 2):

I am sort of partial to my blog [Brew Dudes](http://www.brew-dudes.com/).
Seeing as this is a community wiki, I don't mind pimping my own site.

Answer (score 1):

I run a blog about home brewing and its updated every other day or so.

If you are interested check it out at: [Home Brew Answers](http://www.mashspargeboil.com).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can I add my blog at [www.fairwater-brewery.co.uk](http://www.fairwater-brewery.co.uk/) - it's just my journal of brewing rather than anything desperately exciting or instructional...

For forums I tend to stick with Jim's Beer Kit or The Home Brew Forum, but that's probably 'cause they're UK based and fit with what I'm wanting to brew and the kit I use.

Comment: Absolutely!  I added it to the big list.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently become addicted on drinking pale ale. It makes those german malt flavours sing.

http://ctfinebistro.com/blog/beer/

Answer (score 0):

The posts on [Brewer's Friend](http://www.brewersfriend.com/) are good. And [Northern Brewer](http://northernbrewer.blogspot.com/) has a blog that I just started reading.

As for self-pimpage, here's [my brewing site](http://ianwhitney.com/hopwise/).

Answer (score 0):

The few brewing blogs I have followed don't seem to last very long, or when I do find them they are months (or years) out of date.

However http://homebrewblog.co.uk/ seems to be currently active. And http://www.thehomebrewforum.co.uk/ has strong membership.

Answer (score 0):

http://fluke-brewing.blogspot.com/

Comment: Added this to the big list.

Answer (score 0):

If you stopped by BrewGeeks for a look around then I'd like to buy you a beer.

A virtual beer that is...

-Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I try to provide a great blog for homebrewers over at http://www.orionhomebrewing.com Nearly every batch I brew is also a homebrewing experiment. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

http://homebrewingfun.blogspot.com aka Brain Sparging on Homebrewing is a good homebrewing blog.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like The Mad Fermentationist http://www.themadfermentationist.com/ . He has allot of great resources on sour ales and is very helpful.

http://www.westcoastbrewer.com/ - Homebrewing Blog
http://homebrewingdeal.com/ - Homebrewing Deals